# Custom ArrayAdaptor only calls getView once

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

The only issue i'm having is that getView is only being called once.
I tried to fix it by overriding getCount, so I can verify that it is correctly returning 2.

I've seen several similar posts on here, but most of the fixes had to do with overriding getCount, which I have done.

I know it isn't an issue where I am setting the listview's adaptor because it is actually displaying one item.  I also know it isn't an issue with the layout of the items because getView is only being called once.

```
public class PostAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParseObject> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ParseObject[] values;

    public PostAdapter(Context context, ParseObject[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.post_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);
        //Do stuff
        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return values.length;
    }
}
```

Am I missing any information that could possibly stop this from working?

EDIT: Here is the code where I set the adaptor

```
PostAdapter adapter = new PostAdapter(activity, parseObjects.toArray(new ParseObject[0]));
((ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.postList)).setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Are you sure you construct PostAdapter with an array of two values?

Comment: yes, I've checked that.

Comment: post the code where you set the adapter please

Comment: @pomber Done, but I don't think it matters.  It is doing one of the items, and I've checked to make sure there are 2 items.

Comment: I just tried it with 3 items.  It is only showing the first item.

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint or log in the getCount() method?

Comment: @pomber yes, it gave the correct answer.

Comment: Ooooooh I'm so mad.  I put the listview inside a scrollview, so it hid everything but one item.  It's solved.

Comment: @phil, Even though u put listview inside scrollview...You're getView should call but in the UI front it won't display more than once. Then you're question is wrong

Comment: @HarshaVardhan the way I see it, since the other items are hidden, the adaptor doesn't bother to call getView.